# Keeping angularjs decoupled from an application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm planning out an application that ideally I'd like to keep decoupled from Angular, so all the dom interaction will go into an Angular layer but the core business logic will be kept in a standalone app that is totally unaware of Angular. The two will communicate via Angular services that are able to send messages to the core application.

The standalone app will most likely use requirejs to handle dependency injection.

What I'm unsure of is how to get a module that may be declared something like this:

```
define('AppInteractor', ['require'], function(requre){
    // Set up interactor functionality
});
```

Into an Angular service.

My first though was to have some kind of adapter like this:

```
define(['AppInteractor', 'angular'], function(interactor, angular) {
    var app = angular.module('appInteractor', []).service('AppInteractor', interactor);
});
```

This would register the AppInteractor as a service within an angular module,  the problem with this approach seems to be that because requirejs loads things asynchronously the service hasn't been set when the angular code runs. It also seems to end up with angular loading twice which presumably also doesn't help matters.

I've seen a few articles covering loading all Angular components via require but I was hoping there might be simpler way to make this work.

Can anyone recommend how I might make this work?

Comment: Why do you want to use Angular and at the same time want to have code not aware of Angular? Second, if you want to use the module you have to put it as a dependency in your main module - so you have to require it before.

Comment: I want Angular to handle the dom manipulation / user interaction side of it as it's quite good at that stuff but I don't see the need for my entire application to be dependent on it. Removing that dependency means upgrading to Angular 2 should be easier if needed or replacing it with something like React or Ember becomes possible as it's just a small part of the overall app that would need replacing.

Comment: My opinion is that if you decide to use framework, you should use it. If you at the beginning thinking about changing the framework - you will never have benefits of using it. Your development will be a fight not pleasure. If you like angular - use it. If you don't - use another one.

Comment: I do intend to use it, I'd just like to have a clean layered architecture where the bit that interacts with the dom is kept separate from the core business logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to add a service after the main modules initialization, I recommend you add it to your application module

```
define(['AppInteractor', 'angular'], function(interactor, angular) {
  // There is no second parameter, because we are getting an existing
  // module, not creating a new one.
  var app = angular.module('appModule');
  app.service('AppInteractor', interactor);
});
```

Otherwise, if you want to group all your other logic in a different module, you will need to import the module and add it as a requirement of your application module.

```
define(['AppInteractorModule', 'angular'], function(interactorModule, angular) {
  var app = angular.module('appModule', [interactorModule.name]);
});
```

I also recommend you use a tool like ES6 (6to5, traceur), browserify or Typescript for your module management, and then compile to AMD. I find it easier and cleaner for development.